# How can I retrieve portable executable properties like Version or Description using C++?

Tags: portable-executable

I've been working on an application that is capable of parsing the data of a portable executable reading all the information like Dos header, Nt headers, Sections and so on.
I also want to retrieve the PE properties, the ones shown in the picture below circled in yellow:

[image]

I looked all around the internet and I only found how to edit them using external tools, but I didn't find anything related to how to read them using C++ code.

Any ideas on how to do this? Many thanks!

Comment: Is this a question about the binary format of a PE file, or just how to write a program in C++?

Comment: @MooingDuck It's about writing a program in C++ that is capable of reading such information out of a PE file

Comment: There are a range of function group near `GetFileVersionInfoExW` see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winver/nf-winver-getfileversioninfoexw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is in the `VERSIONINFO` resource.

You need to get it from the PE and parse it. You can find some info about the structure of that resource in the PE here:

[VS_VERSIONINFO structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/vs-versioninfo)